# Is there a way to reverse a cumulative sum column in an R Data Frame?

Tags: r, dataframe, sum, reverse

I'm new to R, and dealing with a Date Frame. I'm looking for a way to create a new column, and populate it with the *reverse* of another column which contains a cumulative sum. I want the individual values added each time.

I have data that looks like this:

| Cumulative Sum |
| --- |
| 0 |
| 4 |
| 9 |
| 18 |
| 33 |

I'd like to create a new column and populate it with the individual value, reversing the cumulative sum, something like the following:

| Cumulative Sum | Individual Value |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 |
| 4 | 4 |
| 9 | 5 |
| 18 | 9 |
| 33 | 15 |

Any and all help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Have a look at `diff`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `diff`, which computes iterated differences.

```
vec=c(0,4,9,18,33)
c(0,diff(vec))
[1]  0  4  5  9 15
```

If you vector does not start with 0, just use `diff(vec)`.

Comment: Thanks so much for your response. This worked a treat. I see that the diff() function returns a vector of length n-1 where the original vector is of length n. So, adding the 0 was perfect.

Comment: I'm glad that it worked for you! You can accept the answer if you think it suffices your demand.